# Adding a property to an Enum

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums, properties

I would like to have an `Enum` with internal property for each enum value, this property can't be set or initialized by the user, but once the user has created `Enum` from a value, he would be able to read (get) this internal property based on the value.

e.g.

```
class Channels(Enum):

    Email     = 1, True   # True is the value of the internal property for value 1
    Sms       = 2, True   # True is the value of the internal property for value 2
    Log       = 3, False  # False is the value of the internal property for value 3
```

Problem is that currently in order to create an instance of this class I need to:
`x = Channels((1, True))` and that's bad. I want to be able to still create instances like: `x = Channels(1)` (i.e. `True` is the internal property of 1, it shouldn't be specified by the user).

My second try was:

```
class Channels2(Enum):

    @DynamicClassAttribute
    def internal_property(self):
        if self.value == 1:
            return True
        elif self.value == 2:
            return True
        elif self.value == 3:
            return False


    Email     = 1
    Sms       = 2
    Log       = 3
```

And this seems to be working (`x = Channels(1)` is working and `x.internal_property` returns `True`, as it should).

The problem here is that it feels not so efficient, executing those if statements every time the `internal_property` is accessed.. Is there any other way making the `Enum` treat `internal_property` as a an extra field of the instance (on top of `Enum` regular `name` and `value` fields)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `__new__()` as [documented here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#when-to-use-new-vs-init) to customize the value of the enum object. For example you can use your original definitions like:

```
from enum import Enum

class Channels(Enum):

    def __new__(cls, value, internal_property):
        obj = object.__new__(cls)
        obj._value_ = value
        obj.internal_property = internal_property
        return obj

    email = 1, True
    sms   = 2, True
    log   = 3, False

print(Channels.email)
# Coordinate.email

print(Channels.email.value)
# 1

print(Channels(3))
# Coordinate.log

print(Channels(3).internal_property)
# False

print(Channels(1).internal_property)
#True
```

Comment: Looks good!  You don't need to inherit from `int`, though -- just do `obj = object.__new__(cls)`

Comment: Thanks @EthanFurman -- I updated the answer. `aenum` looks great!

Answer (score 1):

@MarkMeyer has the `stdlib` solution down well, but if you're looking for easier ways to create `Enum`s you should try [`aenum`](https://pypi.org/project/aenum/)<sup>1</sup>:

```
from aenum import Enum

class Channels(Enum):
    #
    _init_ = 'value internal_property'
    #
    email = 1, True
    sms   = 2, True
    log   = 3, False
```

and in use:

```
>>> list(Channels)
[<Channels.email: 1>, <Channels.sms: 2>, <Channels.log: 3>]

>>> Channels(2)
<Channels.sms: 2>

>>> Channels(2).name
'sms'

>>> Channels(2).internal_property
True
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.